# report builder 3.0 sum group variables out site groupe

Tags: variables, sum, reportbuilder

I have made a row group variable and I want to make a sum out site of the groupe of this variable and not for the multiple values.

The Expression whiche I want to sum is:
=Iif(First(Fields!Starttidspunkt.Value , "ArbDato")=Fields!Starttidspunkt.Value  ,Variables!Normtid.Value , 0) (There are multiple rows with the value in, and i just want the first)

The Variable is like this:
=Iif(Iif(Weekday(Fields!Starttidspunkt.Value) = 1 , 7 , Weekday(Fields!Starttidspunkt.Value) - 1)> Iif(Fields!LigeUligeUge.Value = "Ulige" , Lookup(Fields!Medarbejder.Value , Fields!Fulde_navn.Value , Fields!ArbejdsdageUligeuge.Value , "Medarbejder") , Lookup(Fields!Medarbejder.Value , Fields!Fulde_navn.Value , Fields!ArbejdsdageLigeuge.Value , "Medarbejder")) , 0 ,Parameters!NormTidUge.Value/Iif(Fields!LigeUligeUge.Value = "Ulige" , Lookup(Fields!Medarbejder.Value , Fields!Fulde_navn.Value , Fields!ArbejdsdageUligeuge.Value , "Medarbejder") , Lookup(Fields!Medarbejder.Value , Fields!Fulde_navn.Value , Fields!ArbejdsdageLigeuge.Value , "Medarbejder")))

Can any one help?